# Can't copy unicode(used wchar_t) in HTML format to clipboard

Tags: c++, c, unicode, clipboard, wchar-t

Copying to clipboard in HTML format works when I use **char**,  but if I use **wchar_t** it doesn't work

**When I paste it it's just EMPTY**

here is my code Plase Help me

**Or is there a better way to use unicode(not using wchar_t)? If you do help me**

```
void copyStringEnd(wchar_t *string, wchar_t *buffer)
{
    int i = 0;
    int string_StartIndex = 0;

    while (string[string_StartIndex] != NULL)
    {
        string_StartIndex++;
    }

    while (buffer[i] != NULL)
    {
        string[string_StartIndex + i] = buffer[i];
        i++;
    }
    string[string_StartIndex + i] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t *html = L"abc";
    wchar_t *buf = (wchar_t*)malloc(400 + wcslen(html));

    wcscpy_s(buf, 200,
            L"Version:0.9\r\n"
            L"StartHTML:00000000\r\n"
            L"EndHTML:00000000\r\n"
            L"StartFragment:00000000\r\n"
            L"EndFragment:00000000\r\n"
            L"<html><body>\r\n"
            L"<!--StartFragment -->\r\n");

    copyStringEnd(buf, html);
    copyStringEnd(buf, L"\r\n");

    copyStringEnd(buf,
            L"<!--EndFragment-->\r\n"
            L"</body>\r\n"
            L"</html>");

    wchar_t *ptr = wcsstr(buf, L"StartHTML");
    wsprintfW(ptr + 10, L"%08u", wcsstr(buf, L"<html>") - buf);
    *(ptr + 10 + 8) = '\r';

    ptr = wcsstr(buf, L"EndHTML");
    wsprintfW(ptr + 8, L"%08u", wcslen(buf));
    *(ptr + 8 + 8) = '\r';

    ptr = wcsstr(buf, L"StartFragment");
    wsprintfW(ptr + 14, L"%08u", wcsstr(buf, L"<!--StartFrag") - buf);
    *(ptr + 14 + 8) = '\r';

    ptr = wcsstr(buf, L"EndFragment");
    wsprintfW(ptr + 12, L"%08u", wcsstr(buf, L"<!--EndFrag") - buf);
    *(ptr + 12 + 8) = '\r';



    if (OpenClipboard(NULL)) {
        EmptyClipboard();

        HGLOBAL hText = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, wcslen(buf) * sizeof(wchar_t) + 4);

        wchar_t *ptrs = (wchar_t *)GlobalLock(hText);
        wcscpy_s(ptrs, wcslen(buf) + 2, buf);
        GlobalUnlock(hText);

        SetClipboardData(RegisterClipboardFormatA("HTML Format"), hText);
        CloseClipboard();
        GlobalFree(hText);
    }
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: This is explained in the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917(v=vs.85).aspx "CF_HTML is entirely text format and uses the transformation format UTF-8."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The only character set supported by the clipboard is Unicode in its UTF-8 encoding.

What you're calling "Unicode" is UTF-16-LE. Which is not UTF-8. If you try to interpret UTF-16-LE as UTF-8, it's going to look like it starts with `"V\0"`, and then most code will just treat that `\0` as the end of the string and stop reading.

You need to encode it to UTF-8—which is stored as `char`, not `wchar_t`—and paste that.

Comment: if I used char is it UTF-8 automatically? If it's not how can I encode it?

Comment: Use `WideCharToMultiByte()` to convert a UTF-16 encoded `wchar_t` buffer to a UTF_8 encoded `char` buffer, then you can put the `char` buffer on the clipboard.